# Fullcalendar – custom aspect ratio to each view

Tags: fullcalendar, aspect-ratio

I have read [the documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/aspectRatio/) but I don't understand how to use the code.
What I'd like to have is a custom aspect ratio on each view – to avoid scrollbar in day-view.

How do I implement code to change aspect ratio for week and day view when my fullcalender script is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        weekends: false,
        weekNumbers: true,
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyBGCsyro6GRnVYSGE2uxerWPIh78sjhm9w',
        eventSources: [{
            googleCalendarId: 'oa4lj06jlgehp2sl7f1s7hubi8@group.calendar.google.com',
            rendering: 'inverse-background'
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the only reason to avoid scrollbar in the day view? Because you can also shrink the size of the day view with the [slotDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/) property on `'01:00:00'`. Modifying the options when fullcalendar is instantiated is not implemented and requires a workaround.

Comment: Actually my client would like a 6 months view, so I have made a custom view and to avoid scrolling in the calendar I set the aspectRatio to 0.2 - but then month, week and day are also that high...

Comment: Maybe I could make two calenders and have the 6 month view button outside the "normal" calendar and switch between them. The 6 month view is not for everyday use.

Comment: That is an option. The workaround is destroying the old calendar and create a new fullcalendar instance with the new options.